# Repeated HTML in wordpress functions.php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am creating a few shortcodes In the functions.php file for our wordpress site and am working on how best to implement it.

A selection list of 240 countries that can be chosen from will be in a few different shortcodes and instead of placing the entire list 4 or 5 times I was wondering if we could implement it one time and make the call from within the function.

This is what we have right now:

```
function form_function() {

ob_start(); 
?>
    ...
    <select id="fc" name="fc" title="From Country">
       <option value="United States">United States</option>
       <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
       ...
       <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
    </select>
    ...
    <select id="tc" name="tc" title="To Country">
       <option value="United States">United States</option>
       <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
       ...
       <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
    </select>
    ...
<?php
      $html = ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();
      return $html;
}
```

and we would like to change it to something like:

```
function countrylist() {
    <option value="United States">United States</option>
    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    ...
    <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
 }


function form_function() {

ob_start(); 
?>
    ...
    <select id="fc" name="fc" title="From Country">
      <? countrylist () ?>
    </select>
    ...
    <select id="tc" name="tc" title="To Country">
      <? countrylist () ?>
    </select>
<?php
      $html = ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();
      return $html;
}
```

Any thoughts on how best to do this?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe better change  `countrylist()` function to

```
function countrylist() 
{
    $countries = array('USA', 'Canada', 'Ukraine');        
    foreach($countries as $country)
    {
        $html .= '<option value="'.$country.'">'.$country.'</option>'
    }        
    return $html;
}
```

And in `form_function()` replace `<? countrylist () ?>` with `<?= countrylist () ?>`

Comment: work great except I had to add a ; to the end of $html .= '<option value="'.$country.'">'.$country.'</option>'